# Tablesorter will not display sortable headers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tablesorter

I've been playing with this code for the past 2 hours. I simply cannot find the error. With the code below, the table header and body display, but the headers are not sortable. I've tried various incarnations of the script code, but to no avail. What am I missing?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Mottie-tablesorter-c1ce076/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("table").tablesorter();
        }
    );
    </script>
    </head>
    <?php
    /* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
    server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "SECRET", "SECRET", "SECRET");

    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // Attempt select query execution
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM persons";
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            echo "<table class=\"tablesorter\">";
            echo "<thead>";
             echo "<tr>";
             echo "<th>First Name</th>";
             echo "<th>Last Name</th>";
             echo "<th>Email</th>";
             echo "<th>FFID</th>";
             echo "<th>Street</th>";
             echo "<th>City</th>";
             echo "<th>State</th>";
             echo "<th>Zip</th>";
             echo "<th>Home Fire Dept</th>";
             echo "<th>Shirt Size</th>";
             echo "<th>Additional Shirts</th>";
             echo "<th>Friday Class</th>";
             echo "<th>Saturday Class</th>";
             echo "<th>Sunday Class</th>";
             echo "</tr>";
            echo "</thead>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<tbody><tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['email_address'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['ffid_num'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['address_street'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['address_city'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['address_state'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['address_zip'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['fire_dept'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['wants_tshirt'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['shirt_size'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['additional_shirts'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['friday_class'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['saturday_class'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['sunday_class'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr></tbody>";
            }
            echo "</table>";

            // Close result set
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        } else{
            echo "No records matching your query were found.";
        }
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you try putting <tbody> and </tbody> outside the while loop?

Comment: I did as suggested, but this did not solve the issue.

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer. After doing this the table was indeed sortable. There was just no style, and as such I didn't realize it was sortable until clicking on a header title. Thank you.

Comment: @kimbarcelona Please add your comment as an answer so I can upvote it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add  and  outside the while loop.

```
 echo "</thead><tbody>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['email_address'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['ffid_num'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['address_street'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['address_city'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['address_state'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['address_zip'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['fire_dept'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['wants_tshirt'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['shirt_size'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['additional_shirts'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['friday_class'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['saturday_class'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['sunday_class'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried messaging you, but couldn't for some reason. i was hoping you would come back so I could upvote! Next time I'll just leave a comment like Mottie.

Comment: Alright, I should have posted it as answer because I'm sure about it the first time I saw your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem. It seems the style is critically important as well.

I looked at the source of the example e.g. http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-trigger-sort.html and the only thing missing was the style.
In my case I added:

```
< link href="http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/css/theme.default.css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

and the columns became sortable.
The critical part of the style is I think that it includes the buttons for sorting:

```css
.tablesorter-default thead .headerSortUp,

.tablesorter-default thead .tablesorter-headerSortUp,

.tablesorter-default thead .tablesorter-headerAsc {
    background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFQAEAIAAACMtMP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAVAAQAAAINjI8Bya2wnINUMopZAQA7);
    border-bottom: #000 2px solid;
}

.tablesorter-default thead .headerSortDown,

.tablesorter-default thead .tablesorter-headerSortDown,

.tablesorter-default thead .tablesorter-headerDesc {
    background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFQAEAIAAACMtMP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAVAAQAAAINjB+gC+jP2ptn0WskLQA7);
    border-bottom: #000 2px solid;
}
```

Comment: You are mixing css from the original tablesorter with the css used in my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/)